# How to export mysql table to csv or excel file using phpExcel in CODEIGNITER

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I've been searching on how to export mysql table to csv or excel file. I've seen some steps and I followed them. Is there a way on how to export the mysql table to csv or excel file using codeigniter?

I've tried this PHPExcel. But it seems not working to me.

```
function index()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('filter_result');

    if(!$query)
        return false;

    // Starting the PHPExcel library
    $this->load->library('PHPExcel');
    $this->load->library('PHPExcel/IOFactory');

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none");

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Field names in the first row
    $fields = $query->list_fields();
    $col = 0;
    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
        $col++;
    }

    // Fetching the table data
    $row = 2;
    foreach($query->result() as $data)
    {
        $col = 0;
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $data->$field);
            $col++;
        }

        $row++;
    }

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    // Sending headers to force the user to download the file
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Products_'.date('dMy').'.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

Comment: what does 
 "seems not working to me." means?

Comment: If you want to just start dumping things to a csv file just open up a file handle to php://temp or something, use fputcsv() til you're done with your data, and send that file to the browser with the appropriate headers.

Comment: You can refer to this site. http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a code I use.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  
class excel{

function to_excel($array, $filename) {
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.xls');
    header('Content-type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Pragma: public');
    print "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
    $h = array();
    foreach($array->result_array() as $row){
        foreach($row as $key=>$val){
            if(!in_array($key, $h)){
                $h[] = $key;   
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<table><tr>';
    foreach($h as $key) {
        $key = ucwords($key);
        echo '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach($array->result_array() as $row){
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $val)
            $this->writeRow($val);   
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';


}

function writeRow($val) {
    echo '<td>'.$val.'</td>';              
}

}
?>
```

Create a library with this code and call it as:

```
public function brandExcel() {
    $this->load->library('excel');
    $result = $this->config_model->getBrandsForExcel();
    $this->excel->to_excel($result, 'brands-excel'); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

efenacigiray's answer was great but i got a weird error as the xls is in different format than specified so i just made another function and it works great.

```
class excel {

    function create_excel($array) {
        // Create new PHPExcel object
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        // Set document properties
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                                                   ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                                                   ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                                   ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                                   ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                                                   ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                                                   ->setCategory("Test result file");

        //'id,name,contact_name,email,email2,mobile,mobile2,website,country,city,address,postal_code,info'
        // Add some data
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                          ->setCellValue('A1', 'Id')
                          ->setCellValue('B1', 'name!')
                          ->setCellValue('C1', 'contact_name')
                          ->setCellValue('D1', 'email')
                          ->setCellValue('K1', 'address')
                          ->setCellValue('L1', 'postal_code');
        $i = 2;
        foreach($array as $row){
              $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                          ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $row['id'])
                          ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $row['name'])
                          ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $row['contact_name'])
                          ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $row['email'])
                          ->setCellValue('K'.$i, $row['address'])
                          ->setCellValue('L'.$i, $row['postal_code']);
              $i++;
        }

        // Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
        //          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        //                            ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
        //                            ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

        // Rename worksheet
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Probable Clients');


        // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


        // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="probClients.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

        // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
        header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
        header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
        header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
        header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found efenacigiray's code worked for me too, but I had to remove the code '->result_array()'

Using code igniter version: 2.1.4

(Would have wrote this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet)

Answer (score 0):

for me.

```
print "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM <- this line cuased an error
```

delete this line and use

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />';
```

this meta tag instead.

Thanks to efenacigiray